# Should questions about vague references or minor easter eggs be allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could someone explain this joke to me?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/could-someone-explain-this-joke-to-me)

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76045/who-is-pancakes) is asking about a very small easter egg inside an easter egg level in Diablo 3.  This is most likely something that may be unanswerable to anyone who is not the blizzard developer who put that in.  Should these questions be treated the same as "[why did they allow this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/why-did-they-design-it-that-way-anyway-and-why-do-we-allow-or-disallow-thes) questions (i.e. closed)?"  Any answer to this question would be pure speculation.

Comment: I think we have another meta topic asking about easter eggs. The consensus was "no".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could someone explain this joke to me?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/could-someone-explain-this-joke-to-me); also related: [Is the Google “zerg rush” easter egg on topic?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4593/is-the-google-zerg-rush-easter-egg-on-topic). Looked to me the consensus in both was that yes, questions about easter eggs are allowed.

Comment: Also [this question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/practical-answerable-questions-based-on-actual-problems-that-you-face) which discusses whether the question about the minor easter egg of the impossible space, something only a developer should've known about, in Portal 2 should be closed (again, consensus was that it should be allowed).

Comment: The "zerg rush" question isn't about easter eggs at all; the game itself is an easter egg in a non-game piece of software.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think we need to categorically ban these questions to call a stupid question stupid. (Or, in SE parlance, Downvote or vote to close as NARQ.)

I think, in general, we're far too quick to treat bad questions as symptomatic of problematic categories and ban them outright. This sort of beuracratic navel-gazing is, I think, ultimately counterproductive and self destructive.

Downvote and delete garbage. Upvote and answer good questions. Everything else just gets in the way.

Comment: Hmm, to be honest I think it's actually a good thing that we frequently review broader categories based on a few bad questions.  Doing so early on will help to prevent another ITG debacle -- settle the debate early before it's an entrenched part of the site and emotions run high.  Catching bugs in the design phase, as it were.